# Mongo sum array index

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I would like to get a sum from an array of arrays, but so far I have not found any solution.

The arrays look like this, and I would like to get the sum of all array values `[2]`
[image: Arrays]

So with this array I should get the sum value of 13317 + 4719. I tried using `$sum` but I don't know how to point to the index `2` when it's inside of another array - `$median_sale_prices.2` doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to flatten the array field first by using the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** operator, after which you can then use the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operator as an expression within the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator to sum just the array element in a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step.

The concept can be best explained with the following example:

**Populate test collection**

```
db.test.insert([
    { 
        "x": [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 1]
        ]
    }
])
```

**Run aggregation query**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$x" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": { 
                "$sum": { 
                    "$arrayElemAt": [ "$x", 2 ] 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "total" : 5
}
```

Applying the above to your case becomes trivial.

Comment: One more thing, why isn't this possible

```$multiply: { 
                       parseInt($arrayElemAt: [ "$median_sale_prices", 1 ]),
                       parseInt($arrayElemAt: [ "$median_sale_prices", 2 ])
                    }```

Comment: It's simply not possible because it's not a valid aggregation framework operator.